# Changing the last type in a variadic template

Tags: c++

I actually spotted similar questions but all were related to function argument packs and handling them through `std::tuple`and `std::index_sequence`. I need something different and I can't make the connection myself. Here it is:

Suppose I have a function taking some variadic pack and I want to achieve:

```
template <typename NewVal, template Container, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto foo(Container<T, Ts...> t, NewVal const& v) {
    using OutContainer= Container<NewVal, Same as Ts up to last Type..., but LastElement should be different>
    OutContainer o;
    // fill this new container with v
    return o;
}
```

I observed, in STL, `Allocator` template arguments in containers are always the last one and the type stored is always the first one (don't mind `std::map` now). So, If I want to make a `Container<T>` into a `Container<U>`, I need to handle the last allocator argument as well so that I am using an allocator for this new type. Any ideas?

This is sort of a pseudocode of course, `Container` is a template-template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeding `std::make_index_sequence<N>` or `std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>` to a helper struct or function is usually the easiest way to do non-trivial things to a pack.

To make a helper struct with the type transformation you want, first declare it with the inputs necessary, plus one extra type parameter to take the `std::index_sequence`:

```
namespace foo_detail
{
    template <template <typename...> class Container,
              typename NewFirstT,
              typename NewLastT,
              typename IdxSeq,
              typename ... Tail>
    struct OutContainerHelper;
}
```

Then make a partial specialization that can take any `std::index_sequence<I...>`:

```
namespace foo_detail
{
    template <template <typename...> class Container,
              typename NewFirstT,
              typename NewLastT,
              std::size_t ... I,
              typename ... Tail>
    struct OutContainerHelper<
        Container, NewFirstT, NewLastT, std::index_sequence<I...>, Tail...>
    {
        using type = Container<
            NewFirstT,
            std::conditional_t<(I+1 == sizeof...(Tail)), NewLastT, Tail>...
        >;
    };
}
```

Then just provide a `std::make_index_sequence` or `std::index_sequence_for` as the template argument to the helper:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container,
          typename OldFirstT,
          typename T2,
          typename... Ts,
          typename NewVal>
auto foo(Container<OldFirstT, T2, Ts...> t, NewVal const& v) {
    using NewLastT = ???;
    using OutContainer = typename foo_detail::OutContainerHelper<
        Container, NewVal, NewLastT,
        std::index_sequence_for<T2, Ts...>, T2, Ts...
    >::type;
    OutContainer o;
    // fill this new container with v
    return o;
}
```

(The additional `T2` makes sure the `Container` specialization has at least two template arguments, since the transformation doesn't make sense otherwise. This might make the compile errors a bit less confusing if someone attempts using it with a template that only has one template parameter.)

[Working example on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55b4dd47cc1524ae)